# How can I skip intermediate folders in Python imports?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git-submodules

My python app has a folder structure like this:

```
my_repo/
  src/
    main.py
    util/   <-- util is a git submodule
      src/
        torgle.py
      test/
        test_torgle.py
  test/
    test_main.py
```

Inside `main.py`, I can import stuff in my `util` submodule like this:

```
from util.src.torgle import Torgler
```

But `src/` is just a way to keep things organized in my git submodule repo, and shouldn't really be a logical part of the package name inside the main repo. Is there some way I can skip the `src` part of the module import? I'd rather do this:

```
from util.torgle import Torgler
```

I.e. can I essentially alias `util/src` folder to the Python `util` package?

(Note that in my real case I have more deeply nested packages (`util.x.y.z.torgle`), so `from util import torgle; torgle.Torgler(...)` won't scale well. I'm specifically interested in `from util.torgle import Torgler`.)

Comment: Is there any reason why you build the Python app directly from the repositories, instead of, say, installing it and merging the repository directories in the process?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm no Python expert -- could you say more about what you mean by "installing it"? To clarify my situation, both `my_repo` and `util` are my own repositories; `util` is shared between several projects. So if there's a better way to manage that (and still allow me to import from `util` like `from util.torgle ...`), I'm definitely flexible.

Comment: Are you aware of ``setup.py`` or ``PYTHONPATH``? Basically you can merge your code into one single, installable package, or adjust how Python loads modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can kind of do this by adding my_repo/src/util/__init__.py and adding the following line to it:

```
from .src import torgle
```

You'll then be able to do the following:

```
from util import torgle
torgle.Torgler(...)
```

Comment: Works great, but unfortunately for just one level as shown here. In my real case I have more deeply nested packages (`util.x.y.z.torgle`), so I believe with this technique I would have to do `from util import x; x.y.z.torgle.Torgler(...)`, right? So I'm specifically interested in getting `from util.torgle import Torgler` to work. I've updated the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based on an OS trick, while the one of Benjamin Rowell is python specific and very elegant. I suggest taking a look at it first.

---

The solution are the symbolic links

### **Explanation**

Your situation should be the following:

[image: Directory tree]

Where the actual library is within `useless_dir`, but you want to access it directly.

If you want to import `library.py` from the main file, the standard way is:

```
from useful_dir.useless_dir.library import p_func

p_func()
```

Then, when you call main.py:

```
python3 main.py  # Hello World!
```

### **Here's the trick you are searching for:**

1) Place yourself within the `useful_dir` folder:
[image: Useful directory]

2) From within this directory create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s useless_dir/library.py any_name_for_the_library.py
```

3) Change accordingly the main content:

```
from useful_dir.any_name_for_the_library import p_func

p_func()
```

The end